# The array key is not the row ID value while using result_array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When getting a database result in Codeigniter, the `result_array` method returns the row data, but the array key is not the row ID. What is going wrong?

**Model:**

```
<?php
class Admin_user extends CI_Model
{
    public function list_rows()
    {
        $query = array();
        $query = $this->db->get('content');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php 
foreach ($get_all_content as $key => $values)
{
    $title = $values['title'];
    echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$data['get_all_content'] = $this->admin_user->list_rows();
```

**print_r:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [menu_id] => 12
            [title] => Register Domain name for free
            [sub_title] => This is the sub_title 
            [content] => this is the content description
            [description] => 
            [section] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: Do you `print_r($data['get_all_content'];`? And where did you get your `print_r()`?

Comment: Yes it returns, I did it at view Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [menu_id] => 12 [title] => Register Domain name for free [sub_title] => This is the sub_title [content] => this is the content description [description] => [section] => ) )

Comment: But when you do this `$title = $values['title'];` you are getting the title?

Comment: Yes! am able to get the title values easily

Comment: The key of your data is 0.

Comment: Would you help code it as a example ?

Comment: Whenever I echo the key, it returns 0, How do I get the column of the table ?

Comment: Is all of your indexes changes? When new query comes?

Comment: No it is simple as getting SELECT * FROM `content`, would you explain what do you mean by "Key is 0"

Comment: In the first array 0 is your index then in the second set in your array is your values.

Comment: So you have to foreach those. I'll show you.

Comment: Try my answer if that fits yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $yourdata = [0 => 
      ['id' => 1, 'menu_id' => 12, 'title' => 'Register Domain name for free','sub_title' => 'This is the subtitle', 'content' => 'this content', 'description' => 'description', 'section' => 'sect']
 ];

    foreach($yourdata as $key => $val)
    {
        foreach($val as $key2 => $newVal)
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($key2, $newVal);
              //or echo it echo $key2 and echo $newVal
        }
    }
```

resulted output:

```
  string(2) "id"
    int(1)

  string(7) "menu_id"
    int(12)

  string(5) "title"
  string(29) "Register Domain name for free"

  string(9) "sub_title"
  string(20) "This is the subtitle"

  string(7) "content"
  string(12) "this content"

  string(11) "description"
  string(11) "description"

  string(7) "section"
  string(4) "sect"
```

Comment: it worked :-) thanks for your code example that works, why how does $key in the first loop didn't not worked?

Answer (score 0):

**This is an old question, but I'm answering now for the benefit of new users.**

The short answer is that when you retrieve the results of a database query with `result_array`, you're getting an array of arrays. Each row is it's own array, and the key for that row is NOT the ID column. It is just a sequential number, starting at zero.

For example, if I have a table like this:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | username  | updated    |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 16 | nhageman  | 2019-10-29 |
| 20 | hnoland   | 2014-02-10 |
| 31 | lpostel   | 2020-04-08 |
| 36 | lemmerich | 2016-03-08 |
| 77 | rhegwood  | 2017-02-20 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

...and run an Active Record query like this:

```
$results = $this->db
  ->get('users')
  ->result_array();
```

The `$results` array will look like this:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '16' (length=2)
      'username' => string 'nhageman' (length=8)
      'updated' => string '2019-10-29' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '20' (length=2)
      'username' => string 'hnoland' (length=7)
      'updated' => string '2014-02-10' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '31' (length=2)
      'username' => string 'lpostel' (length=7)
      'updated' => string '2020-04-08' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '36' (length=2)
      'username' => string 'lemmerich' (length=9)
      'updated' => string '2016-03-08' (length=19)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '77' (length=2)
      'username' => string 'rhegwood' (length=8)
      'updated' => string '2017-02-20' (length=19)
```

**Here's the point:**

Notice that the array key for each row is 0 through 4, NOT the row ID.

So you will not get what you expect when you iterate through your array as you did in your question:

```
// how to do it wrong
foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
    echo $key . ':';
    echo $row['username'] . '<br>';
}
```

Wrong results:

```
0: nhageman
1: hnoland
2: lpostel
3: lemmerich
4: rhegwood
```

You can see that the `$key` is just the automatic sequential key assigned to each row. In most cases when dealing with an Active Record result, you can just ignore the key, because the row ID you're looking for is contained in the `$row` array:

```
// how to do it right
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row['id'] . ':';
    echo $row['username'] . '<br>';
}
```

Correct results:

```
16: nhageman
20: hnoland
31: lpostel
36: lemmerich
77: rhegwood
```

Hope this clarifies it for you.